# How to store and retrieve CMSampleBufferRef in an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation framework to read the assets as CMsampleBufferRef and change this as an image and store it in array, how can i store the CMSampleBufferRef directly into array.

```
 I referred CFMutableArray to add, But I am not able to read from that array.
```

Thank in Advance...